# vulnerability in node modules in angular application

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, security

We have below dependency error in security scan. these are giving vulnearability issue

```
  qs
  load-utils
```

but these dependencies are not in `package.json`. I have read in google that it can be indirect dependency.
How to check indirect dependency. is there any way to check.

below is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "infy-02",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "build": "ng build --base-href /finnacle-payment/ ",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.5.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.26",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.12.0",
    "@grapecity/wijmo.all": "5.20203.748",
    "@grapecity/wijmo.angular2.all": "5.20203.748",
    "ansi-html": "0.0.9",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "dd-trace": "2.5.0",
    "engine.io": "4.1.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "helmet": "^3.21.2",
    "ini": "1.3.6",
    "jquery": "3.5.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "knex": "^0.20.11",
    "minimatch": "3.0.6",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "node-forge": "1.0.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-github": "^1.1.0",
    "passport-github2": "^0.1.12",
    "passport-oauth2": "^1.5.0",
    "passport-openidconnect": "0.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "socket.io-parser": "3.3.2",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "wijmo": "5.20203.748",
    "winston": "^3.2.1",
    "xmlhttprequest-ssl": "1.6.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.19",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.19",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

I have tried to search in google but not able to understand on which dependency `qs` or `load-utils` are dependent. could you please help on the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask npm to explain why a package is needed, directly or indirectly:

```
$ npm explain qs
```

If it is an indirect dependency, there is not much you can do about that. You have to wait for the other packages to update their dependencies.

You can however update your own dependencies. This will also update indirect dependencies. For example, Angular is already at version 14 and you are still using Angular 8.